# Como pegar e salvar muitas entradas de dados em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Galera estou começando a programar e ate agora as entradas de dados eram assim:

```
    dado_1 = str(input('Seu nome: '))
    dado_2 = int(input('Sua idade: '))
    dado_3 = str(input('Sexo: '))
```

Mas eu fiquei com uma duvida, como eu pego os mesmos dados acima e os armazeno de forma "infinita" podendo por exemplo salvar 30 nomes ou 100 nomes junto com as outras informações e requisitar depois.

Comment: Comece procurando por listas e laços de repetição (`while`), que é o que precisa de aprender para resolver esse problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variáveis de mesmo tipo podem ser agregadas em uma lista (vou usar a terminologia do **Python**), por exemplo:

```
animais=['cachorro', 'gato', 'galinha']
print(animais)
['cachorro', 'gato', 'galinha']
```

Estes valores podem ser acessados através da sua posição na lista (índice), sendo o primeiro item começando em zero.

```
print(animais[2])
'galinha'
```

E novos valores podem ser facilmente adicionados:

```
animais.append('porco')
print(animais[3])
'porco'
```

Você também pode ter listas podem ter como índice um nome (chave), ao invés de um valor numérico. Em **Python** eles são chamados de dicionários:

```
pessoa = { 'nome': 'Giovanni', 'idade': 45, 'sexo': "M" }
print(pessoa)
{'idade': 45, 'sexo': 'M', 'nome': 'Giovanni'}
```

E cada valor acessado tal qual na lista:

```
print pessoa['idade']
45
```

Neste caso a ordem não é preservada já que você acessa os valores pela chave. E o interessante é que você pode armazenar qualquer par de chave/valor dentro dos dicionários.

Assim pode-se responder sua pergunta com um programa que é mais ou menos assim:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# lista com as pessoas, vazia por enquanto.
pessoas = []

# coloquei apenas 5 para não ficar cansativo mas pode ser qualquer valor.
for i in range(5):
    nome = input('Nome : ')
    idade = int(input('Idade : '))
    sexo = input('Sexo : ')

    # cria um dicionário com o que foi entrado e adiciona à lista.
    pessoas.append({ 'nome': nome, 'idade':idade, 'sexo':sexo })

# e para cada pessoa armazenada...
for pessoa in pessoas:
    # recupera de pessoa tanto 'chave' como 'valor'.
    for chave, valor in pessoa.items():
        print("{} => {}".format(chave, valor))
    print("----")
```

Claro, estes valores estarão na memória apenas enquanto o programa estiver em execução, sendo descartados assim que ele for terminado.

Esta é uma explicação bem básica e vale a pena uma leitura sobre estes dois tipos de dados para, entre outras coisas, conhecer os demais métodos e atributos que podem ser utilizados para trabalhar com o conteúdo deles.